# TypeError: unshift is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, event-handling

I have `todos` `array` of `objects` passed as `props` to a `TodoList` component. I'm trying to add a new `object` to the `array` of `objects`. I created a method called `addTodo` which adds the first `todo`'s `object` & when I tried to add the second todo it fails with the error: `TypeError: this.state.todos.unshift is not a function`.

Two questions:

- Why it fails on the second try & works on the first try?
- how can I fix it?

This is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './TodoListStyles.css'

class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { 
      todos: this.props.todos,
      value: ''
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.unshift({
        id: this.state.todos.length + 1,
        title: this.state.value,
        completed: true
      }),
      value: ''
    });

  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Todos:</h1>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.addTodo(e)}>
          <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
     
        <ul className='todo-list'>
          { 
            this.props.todos.map(
              todo => 
              <React.Fragment key={todo.id}>
                <li className={`todo-item ${todo.completed ? 'todo-item-completed' : ''}`}>{ todo.title }</li>
                <input type='checkbox' checked={todo.completed} />
              </React.Fragment>
            ) 
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

**EDIT:**

I refactored my code based on the explanation answer below to use `concat()` method instead. I got rid of the error, but it doesn't add the `object` to the `array`. This is my new code:

````js
addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const newItem = {
      id: this.state.todos.length + 1,
      title: this.state.value,
      completed: true
    };

    this.setState((prevState) => {
      prevState.todos.concat(newItem)
    })
    
    console.log(this.state.todos)
  }```
````

Comment: Please, never call `this.state.unshift` even if you get it working. The reason is that in React, you want to treat state as immutable, but `unshift` mutates the array it's called on. Make a copy first, then `unshift`. Secondly, `unshift` doesn't return the array, it returns a length of the new array. `concat` is probably a better approach.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I'm doing this project to get to learn React. I come from a professional Vue.js's background. I'll try refactoring this. But why does it even work the first time though?

Comment: It's not terribly productive to speculate on what React is doing when you are breaking the immutability rule because it dips into basically unpredictable implementation details. Start with defined behavior, then you can reason about it. I added an answer that hopefully helps explain what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) is an in-place function that mutates the array it's called upon. `unshift` returns the length of the updated array. The reason it fails after adding an item is because you've replaced what should be an array with a number. `Number.map` is not a thing so the program crashes.

The golden rule of React is ["never mutate state"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really) because it confuses React's diffing algorithm as it attempts to figure out what to rerender, with unpredictable results. Make a copy if you need to use a mutating function like `unshift`.

Try [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of `unshift` here. `concat` is non-mutating and returns a copy of the array it's called on, so there will be no problems with React and it's safe to use inline directly in the object you're passing to `setState`.

A second problem is [reading state values inside of the `setState` call](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), like `this.state.todos.length`. Use the callback version of `setState` that accepts the previous state as a parameter:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  todos: [{
    id: prevState.todos.length + 1,
    title: prevState.value,
    completed: true
  }].concat(prevState.todos)
}));
```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) works in place of `concat` here. The code below also fixes a bug where `this.props.map` was used instead of `this.state.map` and doesn't use an `<input>` as a child element of a `<ul>`.

```js
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos: this.props.todos,
      value: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  addTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todos: [{
        id: prevState.todos.length + 1,
        title: prevState.value,
        completed: true
      }, ...prevState.todos]
    }));
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Todos:</h1>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.addTodo(e)}>
          <input type='text' 
                 value={this.state.value} 
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
        <ul className='todo-list'>
          { 
            this.state.todos.map(todo =>              
              <React.Fragment key={todo.id}>
                <li className={
                  `todo-item ${todo.completed 
                   ? 'todo-item-completed' 
                   : ''}`
                }>
                  { todo.title }
                  <input
                    readOnly
                    type='checkbox'
                    checked={todo.completed}
                  />
                </li>
              </React.Fragment>
            ) 
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<TodoList todos={[]} />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Using [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) and the [state hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) moves pieces of state into distinct variables, simplifying state management in most use cases.

As a side note, `prevState.todos.length + 1` may be a poor way to generate ids if you introduce the option to delete todos. I could add a todo and make the length 1, add a second todo to make the length 2. Then, if I delete the first item with id 1 and create a new item, I have two items with id set to 2. A monotonically increasing number or UUID might be better.

Comment: Does it work on your side? I'm getting this error: `TypeError: {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)}.concat is not a function`

Comment: Updated! My mistake--I tried calling `concat` on an object rather than an array. You can also use spread here. Let me know if it doesn't work after the update, I haven't tested this code.

Comment: It still doesn't add it to the `array` of `objects` :( I get no errors though. Man, React is hard. It's even hard & tricky for experienced React devs like yourself. Thanks for all the help btw

Comment: My bad! It did add it to the `array`, but it didn't cause the re-render cause I was doing `this.props.todos` instead of `this.state.todos` . Thanks for all the help. I will need reread all your posts, but it seems awfully complicated to accomplish something so simple in React. Btw, I'm using class components because the code base I will be working uses it :(

Comment: Good catch--I noticed that too. Can you use React hooks? I find them much easier than class components. IIf you've tried Angular it might put React in perspective a bit...

Comment: > Can you use React hooks? Not for now, I'm trying to contribute to an open-source project based on React which the code base is mostly written in-class component, but i might refactor my code later for practice & learning! Thanks again